# How to recreate reference node in a neo4j database after i have deleted it?

Tags: neo4j

I writed my java code like this:

```
GraphDatabaseService dblp =new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("GraphDb/dblp");
((EmbeddedGraphDatabase) dblp).getConfig().getGraphDbModule().createNewReferenceNode();
```

as you see, but it doesn't work.
so, i want to know how should i do to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not persisted :(

So you can use the Neo4j batch-inserter to create a new node with id 0.

```
BatchInserter inserter = 
     BatchInserters.inserter( "target/batchinserter-example", fileSystem );
inserter.createNode(0,new HashMap());
inserter.shutdown();
```